# Adding css class to a dynamically created row using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a jsp page in which rows of a table are added dynamically. Here I am using a different java script than the one in my previous question. Here I could add elements into table columns, but I could not apply style class which is already defined in a css file.

my java script function is

```
function addrow(tableID) {
    try{
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);


    var i=0;
    var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML ='<h4>Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>';

    i++;
    newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML ='<input type="text" name="type7" id="type8" size="30"/>';
    i++;
    newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML ='';
    i++;
    newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML ='<h4>Description &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>';
    i++;
    newcell = row.insertCell(i);
    newcell.innerHTML ='<textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2" cols="28" rows="2"></textarea>';

}catch(e) {
    alert(e);
}
}
```

My HTML part is

```
<table id="table1" width="792" border="0">

<tr class="rowdiv">
      <td class="formlabel"><h4>Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4></td>
      <td class="formfield"><input type="text" name="type7" id="type8" size="30"/></td>
      <td class="formgap"></td>
      <td class="formlabel"><h4>Description &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4></td>
      <td class="formfield"><textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2" cols="28" rows="2"></textarea></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="rowdiv">
        <td width="170" class="formlabel">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="formfield">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="formgap"></td>
        <td class="formlabel">&nbsp;</td>
        <td class="formfield"><h6 onclick="addrow('table1')">Add policy</h6></td>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

I need to apply the same styles classes formlabel, formfield and formgap in the newly created rows also.

I tried in googled but got some codes which will extract the style attributes one by one and copy to new row. But that is not what I want, I need to put the class names itself.

MY css part is

```
.formlabel{                         /* fields label's style  */
    text-align: right;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: lighter;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:#000000;
}
.formlabel a{                           /* fields label's style  */
    text-align: right;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
        text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:#FF0000;
}
.formlabel a:HOVER{                         /* fields label's style  */
    text-align: right;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
        text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:navy;
}
.formfield {                            /* field style */
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:1px;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;

    color:#000000;
}
.formfield textarea{                            /* field style */
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:1px;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-transform: none;
width:185px;
    color:#000000;
}
.formfield a{                           /* field style */
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:1px;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:#FF0000;
}
.formfield a:HOVER{                         /* field style */
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:1px;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration:none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color:navy;
}
.loginformfield {                           /* field style */
    text-align: left;
    margin-left:1px;
    font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
.formfield input {text-transform: capitalize;`font:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;}

.formlabel h5{margin: opx;padding: opx; font-weight: lighter;}
.formfield h6{margin: opx;padding: opx; font-weight: lighter;}
```

Comment: Just as a note, it looks like you're setting an `id` attribute on one of the dynamically created elements, but you're just using a static value. IDs on elements need to be unique.

Comment: Did you try newcell.class = newcell.className = "yourclass" ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The class(es) of an element are stored in the `className` property, so try calling `newcell.className = 'yourclassname';` for the cells you want to add a class to.

Comment: @sarin I'm glad it works. However, if one of the two answers provided helped you solve your problem, I'm confused as to why you didn't accept one of those as the answer, and instead opted to post your now working code as an answer and accept that...

Comment: Please look into this questions also..

http://stackoverflow.com/q/9110044/1184697

Comment: I was trying with cell.addClass(<className>) and it was not working, Thanks for your example, that worked !!!

Answer (score 4):

```
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);
row.className = "rowdiv";

var i=0;
var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<h4>Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>';
newcell.className = "formlabel";

i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<input type="text" name="type7" id="type8" size="30"/>';
newcell.className = "formfield";

i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='';
newcell.className = "formgap";

i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<h4>Description &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>';
newcell.className = "formlabel";

i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2" cols="28" rows="2"></textarea>';
newcell.className = "formfield";
```

Comment: Please look into this questions also..

http://stackoverflow.com/q/9110044/1184697

Answer (score 1):

```
var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<h4>Type &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>';
newcell.className = 'formlabel';
i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<input type="text" name="type7" id="type8" size="30"/>';
newcell.className = 'formfield';
i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='';
newcell.className = 'formgap';
i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<h4>Description &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</h4>';
newcell.className = 'formlabel';
i++;
newcell = row.insertCell(i);
newcell.innerHTML ='<textarea name="textarea2" id="textarea2" cols="28" rows="2"></textarea>';
newcell.className = 'formfield';
```

Comment: Please look into this questions also..

http://stackoverflow.com/q/9110044/1184697